# Automatically add all the dll in Xamarin Forms PCL

Tags: xamarin.forms, nuget

I am trying to create a Nuget Package - I followed these steps https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/nuget/

Is there a way to automatically generate this  tag with any available command to create a nuspec file

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the command "nuget spec". It just creates empty template.

Your nuspec file could look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>Your ID</id>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <authors>Whatever name</authors>
    <owners>Wahtever name</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Blah blah</description>
    <releaseNotes></releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2017</copyright>
    <tags></tags>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework="portable-net45+win+wpa81+wp80">
        <!-- Your nuget packages dependencies -->
      </group>
      <group targetFramework="MonoAndroid10">
        <!-- Your nuget packages dependencies -->
      </group>
      <group targetFramework="Xamarin.iOS10">
        <!-- Your nuget packages dependencies -->
      </group>
      <group targetFramework="uap">
        <!-- Your nuget packages dependencies -->
      </group>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
    <files>
     <!--Portable-->
     <file src="..\YourProjectName\Plugin.YourProjectName\bin\Release\Plugin.YourProjectName.*" target="lib\portable-net45+win+wpa81+wp80" />

     <!--Xamarin.Android-->
     <file src="..\YourProjectName\Plugin.YourProjectName.Android\bin\Release\Plugin.YourProjectName.*" target="lib\MonoAndroid10" />

     <!--Xamarin.iOS-->
     <file src="..\YourProjectName\Plugin.YourProjectName.iOS\bin\iPhone\Release\Plugin.YourProjectName.*" target="lib\Xamarin.iOS10" />

     <!--UWP-->
     <file src="..\YourProjectName\Plugin.YourProjectName.UWP\bin\Release\Plugin.YourProjectName.*" target="lib\UAP10" />
  </files>
</package>
```

There is template for Visual Studio 2015 [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-473885.PluginForXamarinTemplates). As a reference you can follow this [project](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/VibratePlugin).

In case that you don't need to write any platform specific code for iOS, Android or UWP create in Visual Studio 2017 .NET standard class library targeting framework .NET Standard 1.4.

Open project properties and change target framework. Then in the tab "Package" check "Generate Nuget package on build".

Comment: Anything for Mac OS??

Comment: In case that you don't need to write any platform specific code this is the same for MAC. Otherwise clone the Vibrate plugin and see how nuget project is structured. This repo is great example how to start creating nuget packages plus it is using .net standard, which you want to use.