# James Montenegro : extension "Plugin For Xamarin Templates" for UWP

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I want to create a plugin for Xamarin Forms. I tried that with extension "Plugin For Xamarin Templates" but when I create the project it throws this error : [image]

And the "Solution Explorer" only shows Android , IOS and PLC projects.

Comment: What Visual Studio you have?

Comment: i have VS 2017 15.4.4

Answer (score 1):

This template is determined for Visual Studio 2015. If you want to use it in VS2017 install Visual Studio 2015. Then create project template in VS2015 and remove Windows Phone projects. After that you can open in Visual Studio 2017.

In case that you don't want to install VS2015 you can do everything manually. Follow my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47191429/automatically-add-all-the-dll-in-xamarin-forms-pcl/47197109#47197109).